# App stops whenever I press back button

Tags: android

Problem: This only happening on some pages. when I press back app stops. I get this error. I am not able to figure it out the exact problem. I am new to android. and this is happening at many pages.Any help would be highly appreciated.

logcat error:

```
    InputEventSender:Exception dispatching finished signal.E/MessageQueue-JNI:Exception in MessageQueue callback:handleReceiveCallbackE/MessageQueue-JNI:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.close()' on a null object reference at twik.in.DBHelper.close(DBHelper.java:102)at twik.in.ActivityMenuDetail.onBackPressed(ActivityMenuDetail.java:285)at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2477)at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2664)at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2730)
```

In error these two classes are mentioned so I am posting its code here

```
public class ActivityMenuDetail extends Activity {

ImageView imgPreview;
TextView txtText, txtSubText;
WebView txtDescription;
Button btnAdd;
ScrollView sclDetail;
ProgressBar prgLoading;
TextView txtAlert;

// declare dbhelper object
static DBHelper dbhelper;

// declare ImageLoader object
ImageLoader imageLoader;

// declare variables to store menu data
String Menu_image, Menu_name, Menu_serve, Menu_description;
double Menu_price;
int Menu_quantity;
long Menu_ID;
String MenuDetailAPI;
int IOConnect = 0;

// create price format
DecimalFormat formatData = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_detail);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.header)));
    bar.setTitle("Service Centre Detail");
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);
    txtSubText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSubText);
    txtDescription = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    //btnShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
    sclDetail = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sclDetail);
    prgLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prgLoading);
    txtAlert = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAlert);

    // get screen device width and height
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int wPix = dm.widthPixels;
    int hPix = wPix / 2 + 50;

    // change menu image width and height
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wPix, hPix);
    imgPreview.setLayoutParams(lp);

    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(ActivityMenuDetail.this);
    dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);

    // get menu id that sent from previous page
    Intent iGet = getIntent();
    Menu_ID = iGet.getLongExtra("menu_id", 0);

    // Menu detail API url
    MenuDetailAPI = Constant.MenuDetailAPI+"?accesskey="+Constant.AccessKey+"&menu_id="+Menu_ID;

    // call asynctask class to request data from server
    new getDataTask().execute();      

    // event listener to handle add button when clicked
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // show input dialog
            addtoCart();
        }
    });



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.cart:
        // refresh action
        Intent iMyOrder = new Intent(ActivityMenuDetail.this, ActivityCart.class);
        startActivity(iMyOrder);
        overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_next);
        return true;

    case android.R.id.home:
        // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
        this.finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

// method to show number of order form

void addtoCart(){
     // open database first
    try{
        dbhelper.openDataBase();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        throw sqle;
    }

    if(dbhelper.isDataExist(Menu_ID)){
        dbhelper.updateData(Menu_ID, 1, (Menu_price));
    }else{
        dbhelper.addData(Menu_ID, Menu_name, 1, (Menu_price));
    }

    startActivity(new Intent(ActivityMenuDetail.this,ActivityCart.class));

};

// asynctask class to handle parsing json in background
public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    // show progressbar first
    getDataTask(){
        if(!prgLoading.isShown()){
            prgLoading.setVisibility(0);
            txtAlert.setVisibility(8);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // parse json data from server in background
        parseJSONData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
        // if internet connection and data available show data
        // otherwise, show alert text
        if((Menu_name != null) && IOConnect == 0){
            sclDetail.setVisibility(0);

            imageLoader.DisplayImage(Constant.AdminPageURL+Menu_image, imgPreview);

            txtText.setText(Menu_name);
            txtSubText.setText("Price : " +Menu_price+" "+ActivityMenuList.Currency+"\n"+"Status : "+Menu_serve+"\n"+"Empty Slots : "+Menu_quantity);
            txtDescription.loadDataWithBaseURL("", Menu_description, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
            txtDescription.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e7e7e7"));
        }else{
            txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
        }
    }
}

// method to parse json data from server
public void parseJSONData(){

    try {
        // request data from menu detail API
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(MenuDetailAPI);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }

        // parse json data and store into tax and currency variables
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 

            JSONObject menu = object.getJSONObject("Menu_detail");

            Menu_image = menu.getString("Menu_image");
            Menu_name = menu.getString("Menu_name");
            Menu_price = Double.valueOf(formatData.format(menu.getDouble("Price")));
            Menu_serve = menu.getString("Serve_for");
            Menu_description = menu.getString("Description");
            Menu_quantity = menu.getInt("Quantity");

        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}


// close database before back to previous page
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    dbhelper.close();
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //imageLoader.clearCache();
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig)
{
    // Ignore orientation change to keep activity from restarting
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

and debhelper class here

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

String DB_PATH;
private final static String DB_NAME = "db_order";
public final static int DB_VERSION = 1;
public static SQLiteDatabase db; 

private final Context context;

private final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_order";
private final String ID = "id";
private final String MENU_NAME = "Menu_name";
private final String QUANTITY = "Quantity";
private final String TOTAL_PRICE = "Total_price";


public DBHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.context = context;

    DB_PATH = Constant.DBPath;
}   

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;


    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist

    }else{
        db_Read = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db_Read.close();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }

}



private boolean checkDataBase(){

    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);

    return dbFile.exists();

}


private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

@Override
public void close() {
    db.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

/** this code is used to get all data from database */
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllData(){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> dataArrays = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

    Cursor cursor = null;

        try{
            cursor = db.query(
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[]{ID, MENU_NAME, QUANTITY, TOTAL_PRICE},
                    null,null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            if (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                do{
                    ArrayList<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                    dataList.add(cursor.getLong(0));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(2));
                    dataList.add(cursor.getString(3));

                    dataArrays.add(dataList);
                }

                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return dataArrays;
}

/** this code is used to get all data from database */
public boolean isDataExist(long id){
    boolean exist = false;

    Cursor cursor = null;

        try{
            cursor = db.query(
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[]{ID},
                    ID +"="+id,
                    null, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                exist = true;
            }

            cursor.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return exist;
}

/** this code is used to get all data from database */
public boolean isPreviousDataExist(){
    boolean exist = false;

    Cursor cursor = null;

        try{
            cursor = db.query(
                    TABLE_NAME,
                    new String[]{ID},
                    null,null, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                exist = true;
            }

            cursor.close();
        }catch (SQLException e){
            Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return exist;
}

public void addData(long id, String menu_name, int quantity, double total_price){
    // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ID, id);
    values.put(MENU_NAME, menu_name);
    values.put(QUANTITY, quantity);
    values.put(TOTAL_PRICE, total_price);

    // ask the database object to insert the new data 
    try{db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void deleteData(long id){
    // ask the database manager to delete the row of given id
    try {db.delete(TABLE_NAME, ID + "=" + id, null);}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void deleteAllData(){
    // ask the database manager to delete the row of given id
    try {db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void updateData(long id, int quantity, double total_price){
    // this is a key value pair holder used by android's SQLite functions
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(QUANTITY, quantity);
    values.put(TOTAL_PRICE, total_price);

    // ask the database object to update the database row of given rowID
    try {db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, ID + "=" + id, null);}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB Error", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: just change to this if(dbhelper!=null){dbhelper.close();}

Comment: Remove `super.onBackPressed();` from `onBackPressed()` method

Comment: removed it but still crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error trace that you have provided, it seems that "db" instance in DBHelper is null.  Therefore in your onBackPressed() when you try to close db by called dbHelper.close(), it's throwing the NullPointerException.  Adding a null check will help.

// close database before back to previous page
@Override

```
public void onBackPressed() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onBackPressed();
dbhelper.close();
finish();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
}
```

The above function will eventually call the function below:

```
@Override
public void close() {
db.close();
}
```

Add a null check for "db"

```
@Override
public void close() {
if (db != null) {
    db.close();
}
}
```

In a quick glance of your code, it seems that you are opening DB only on action like "add to cart".

```
void addtoCart(){
 // open database first
try{
    dbhelper.openDataBase();
}catch(SQLException sqle){
    throw sqle;
}

if(dbhelper.isDataExist(Menu_ID)){
    dbhelper.updateData(Menu_ID, 1, (Menu_price));
}else{
    dbhelper.addData(Menu_ID, Menu_name, 1, (Menu_price));
}

startActivity(new Intent(ActivityMenuDetail.this,ActivityCart.class));

};
```

If you try to close the screen without performing such action DB object would not be available.

Comment: You are to the point. When I open my cart page in app after that it never crashes. but if I dont open it and naviagte elsewhere it crashes. How to fix it. Novice here. Its a pain point. You caught the exact behaviour. Plz suggest soln

Comment: It's simple.  Add a null check before closing the DB.  I have mentioned the same in the snipper above too.  Add a check in the DBHelper class itself in the close() method.  Surround "db.close()" with a if clause checking for db null.

Comment: when I add the above code @override becomes red and say it doesn't override method from the upperclass. It would be great if you post an elaborated way to do what you suggest. All above soln hasn't worked yet.

Comment: You need to update the already existing 
public void close() method available in your DBHelper.java

As a quicky replace that existing function with the one below:
@Override
public void close() {
    if (db != null) db.close();
}

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: This solved the problem..first I could not understand what you said then @Ashwini kutre helped me do it. A big thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1):

The logcat says your `dbhelper` object is null when preforming `close()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (dbhelper != null)
        dbhelper.close();
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
}
```

That should fix the problem

Comment: with the same logcat? please add the new logcat

Comment: posting the new log in a minute. Studio crashed on low ram.

Comment: This is what I got when I implemented above code    this is the log InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal. MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.close()' on a null object reference at twik.in.DBHelper.close(DBHelper.java:102) at twik.in.ActivityMenuDetail.onBackPressed(ActivityMenuDetail.java:284)

Comment: wow.. thats peculiar. clean the project and re run the code. maybe instant run is messing around, and if possible uninstall the app from the test device and rerun the code

Comment: I am running on emulator. I cleaned it and re ran it. still closes. With above error. Looks like I am stuck forever.

Comment: move the `dbhelper.close()` with the if to `onPause()`

Answer (score 0):

According to logcat you dbhelper is null, so its giving a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    dbhelper.close();
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
}
```

In the above method, `super.onBackPressed();` is called first before closing the database, which is not a good practice.

Change it to,

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (dbhelper != null)
            dbhelper.close();
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Also change,

```
public void close() {
db.close();
}
```

to

```
public void close() {
if(db!=null)
db.close();
}
```

in Dbhelper.class

Comment: Changed it to what you suggested. Still crashing.

Comment: What does the logcat say now?

Comment: Try removing `super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: removed it. still crashed. posting new logcat here

Comment: after removing super.onbackpressed(); ...this is the log   InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal.
MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.close()' on a null object reference
at twik.in.DBHelper.close(DBHelper.java:102)
at twik.in.ActivityMenuDetail.onBackPressed(ActivityMenuDetail.java:284)

Comment: I do not see any log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116455/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-ashwini-kutre).

Answer (score 0):

This is because it may getting null object reference of dbhelper and also it doesn't need to use finish(); as when onBackPressed() called activity finished automatically.

```
if (dbhelper != null)
            dbhelper.close();
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
        super.onBackPressed();
```